# Как вывести список файлов в директории при помощи Django + Django REST + AngularJS?

Tags: python, django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

Как правильно организовать работу с данными, для которых нет модели в бд? Вывод этих данных на страницу, и взаимодействие с уже существующей моделью.

Использую Django, Django REST и AngularJS. Сейчас у меня страницы генерируются таким образом: есть модель в models.py, сериализатор для нее в serializers.py, в view.py - представление. В controllers.js - контроллер, который используется в templates.

Не могу сообразить, как прикрутить страницу для вывода списка файлов в нескольких директориях? Если я правильно понимаю, для этого создавать модель не нужно? Только представление? Ведь я буду брать список файлов не из бд. Но при этом мне нужно выделить те файлы, которые уже есть в бд (в виде существующей модели).
Предположим, пример, как получить список файлов в директории, я нашел:

```
import os

script_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)

pathToImagesFiles = os.path.join(script_directory, 'img')

for file in os.listdir(pathToImagesFiles):
    if file.endswith(".png"):
        print (file.split('.')[0], file.split('.')[1])
```

В urls.py я добавил:

```
url(r'^mypage$', 'myproject.views.get_files')
```

в views.py добавил функцию (без класса):

```
def get_files(request):
    return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', {'var': 'v1'})
```

var - пытаюсь вывести для примера, но передается пустое значение:

в mytemplate.html:
вывожу

```
{{ var }}
```

Пытался делать через метод класса во view.py:

```
class MyClassView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'mytemplate.html'
```

но как туда передать список файлов? На ум приходит только через $http.get() в контроллере для AngularJS вызов какого-то метода для API... Только как это реализовать?

Или пробовал через:

```
class MyClassView(ListView):
   template_name = 'mytemplate.html'
   здесь должна быть модель, которая вроде как мне не нужна
```

Еще пытался через `class MyClassAPI (generics.ListAPIView)` но сериализаторов-то нет, и сериализовывать нечего, т.к. нет модели.

**Обновление:**
Добавил в views.py:

```
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class MyView(ListView):
    template_name = 'mytemplate.html'

class MyAPI(APIView)
    permission_classes = {
       permissions.AllowAny
    ]

def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return Response({'var': 'v1'})
```

в общий urls.py добавил:

```
url(r'^mypage$', MyView.as_view())
 url(r'^api/', imclude('myapp.urls'))
```

в другой urls.py (для myapp) добавил

```
url(r'^mypage$', MyAPI.as_view())
```

В controllers.py:
добавил контроллер, в нем

```
$http.get('api/mypage') ....
```

При переходе на .../api/mypage REST выдает ошибку, что GET не разрешен, а можно только POST и OPTIONS.

На странице шаблона - ошибка 403 FORBIDDEN.
Предположим, я меняю на `$http.post('api/mypage')` - ошибка та же.
В теле ответа ругается на CSRF.

**Обновление 2:**
Добавил в class MyAPI

```
api_view = ['GET', 'POST']
```

и 
метод `get(...)`
аналогичный post, только значение var = v2

REST теперь разрешает GET. При открытии в браузере .../api/mypage
Выдает правильный ответ (var = v2)

При загрузке шаблона та же ошибка 403. С CSRF проблем не возникало до этого.

**Обновление 3:**
При замене в контроллере метода $http.post на $http.get ответ верный.